# How to write a function that accepts predetermined keys by only value, then the rest as arbitrary key=value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is for an Intro to Python course, and additionally the instructions require us to **not** import any additional modules or use any methods that haven't been covered by our coursework.  This readily eliminates almost any solution I'm able to find.

**The assignment specifies:**
Write a function that stores information...in a dictionary.  The function should always receive [key1] and [key2].  It should then accept an arbitrary number of keyword arguments.  Call the function with the required information and two other name-value pairs.

Your function should accept a call such as:

`add = yourfunc('value1', 'value2', key3='value3', key4='value4')`

and output:

```
>>>{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}
{ see below }
```

where "see below" consists of another dicitonary with different values in different order, but include 'key1': 'other1' and 'key2': 'other2', presumably data stored from a previous function call.

The closest that I can figure on my own is this:

```
def dict(key1 = None, key2 = None, **extra):

    print (key1, key2, extra)

def makedict():

    dict('value1', 'value2', key3='value3', key4='value4')

makedict()
```

However, this outputs:

```
>>>value1 value2 {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't call your function `dict()`. That's the name of the built-in function for creating dictionaries.

Comment: And your function just prints the values, it doesn't create a dictionary like the assignment said.

Comment: Is your function supposed to create a new dictionary and return it, or accept an existing dictionary and add the provided key/value pairs to this dictionary?

Comment: @Vin I believe it's supposed to create a new one and return it rather than consolidating/updating just one.  I'm inferring this based upon the assignment example output that was given, since there were two distinct dictionaries in the output.

Comment: Can anyone clarify what needs to be improved with this question?  I get my naming convention was not optimal, was there anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function just prints its arguments, it doesn't create a dictionary.

Since the first two arguments must always be supplied, you shouldn't give them default values.

By convention the name we use for arbitrary keyword arguments is `kwargs`.

Don't name your function `dict()`, since that's the name of the built-in type, and it's the function you need to call to actually create the dictionary.

```
def yourfunc(val1, val2, **kwargs):
    return dict(key1 = val1, key2 = val2, **kwargs)

print(yourfunc('value1', 'value2', key3='value3', key4='value4'))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite understanding how to translate this over to the format stated in the assignment (I'm aware the assignment itself is worded a bit ambiguously).  I've been trying to adapt it accordingly for the last 2 hours, but I keep getting `TypeError: yourfunc() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'key1' and 'key2'`?

Comment: I've added the call

Answer (score 2):

You are missing several things in an ideal implementation of the problem described. First of all you should initialize an empty dictionary to store the default keys (key1 and key2) and later add the new key-value pairs based on the arbitrary numbers received by the **extra parameter in your function.

Based on your current implementation I would make the following corrections:

```
def dict(value1, value2, **extra):
    # Initialize empty dictionary
    default_dict = {}
    
    # Creating default key-value pairs
    default_dict['key1'] = value1
    default_dict['key2'] = value2
    
    # Iterate over arbitrary number of key-value pairs
    for key, value in extra.items():
      default_dict[key]=value
    
    print(default_dict)

def makedict():

    dict('value1', 'value2', key3='value3', key4='value4')

makedict()
```

You can read more about Keyword Arguments in the [python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

Comment: This is a good approach, but there's an edge case where if one of the "extra" keys is "key1" or "key2", the later provided value will override the initially provided value. The answer from @Barmar above addresses this by invoking the dictionary constructor. If "key1 "appears twice among the arguments to the constructor, this will trigger an exception and prevent the ambiguity from passing silently.

Comment: Thank you! That's indeed an edge case I missed

Comment: Don't name the function `dict`, there's already a built-in type/function with this name.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should make `key1` and `key2` mandatory arguments (by not giving them default values). When you make the dictionary, you want to combine those two values them with the arbitrary number of additional keywords you receive with `**kwargs`.

```
def yourfunc(key1, key2, **kwargs):
    return {'key1':key1, 'key2':key2, **kwargs}
```

The unpacking of `**kwargs` in a dictionary literal only works in versions of Python >= 3.5 (which isn't really all that recent). If you want to support older versions, you could do the same thing in multiple steps (or you could call the builtin `dict` constructor):

```
def yourfunc(key1, key2, **kwargs):
    my_dict = {'key1':key1, 'key2':key2}
    my_dict.update(kwargs)
    return my_dict
```

By the way, I'm assuming you want to *return* the dictionary you store the argument data in, rather than just printing it. You could do that instead, if it's what you're actually expected to do (the assignment seems ambiguous to me).

Those functions do *allow* the caller to pass `key1` and `key2` as keyword arguments (but they can *also* work as positional arguments). If you want them to *only* work as positional arguments, more recent versions of Python (>=     3.8) can do that too. You can use a `/` to mark the end of positional-only arguments:

```
def yourfunc(key1, key2, /, **kwargs):
   ...
```